# Apache POI is very slow

Tags: java, excel, apache, logging, apache-poi

I am trying to export xls file. But apache poi is very slow for some reason. I cant see any logs, so seems logging is turned off. This is my code. Exporting data not so big(3000 rows). WebSphere Portal 7.0. Help, pls.

```
if (divideBySchool==null || (!sessionApplicationTypeId.equals(PROGRAM_DIRECT) && !sessionApplicationTypeId.equals(PROGRAM_FOUNDATION) && !sessionApplicationTypeId.equals(PROGRAM_TRANSFER))){

                        List<RField> formFields = sbLocal.getFieldsByApplicationType(sessionApplicationTypeId, fieldsToTake);
                        int colNum=2;
                        int rowNum=0;

                        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
                        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(1);
                        cell.setCellValue("Applicant ID");
                        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 256*25);

                        for (RField rField : formFields) {
                            cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum);
                            cell.setCellValue(rField.getName());
                            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
                            sheet.setColumnWidth(colNum, 256*25);
                            colNum++;
                        }   

                        cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum);
                        cell.setCellValue("Applicant status");
                        cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(colNum, 256*25);

                        if (fieldsToTake.equals(IN_EXAM)){
                            cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum+1);
                            cell.setCellValue("Exam status");
                            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
                            sheet.setColumnWidth(colNum, 256*25);

                            cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum+2);
                            cell.setCellValue("Note");
                            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
                            sheet.setColumnWidth(colNum, 256*25);
                        }   

                        System.out.println("Time for label ==============>" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        rowNum++;
                        int k=1;

                        for (int i = 0; i < applicants.length(); i++)  {
                            headerRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

                            cell = headerRow.createCell(0);
                            cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(k));
                            //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));

                            cell = headerRow.createCell(1);
                            cell.setCellValue(applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString("APPLICANT_ID"));
                            //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));

                            colNum=2;
                            for (RField rField : formFields) {
                                if (applicants.getJSONObject(i).has(String.valueOf(rField.getFieldId()))){
                                    //rField.getRFieldType().getFieldTypeId()
                                    String value = applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString(String.valueOf(rField.getFieldId()));
                                    if(rField.getRFieldType().getFieldTypeId() == 3 && rField.getFieldId() != 797){
                                        value = value.split(" ")[0];
                                    }
                                    cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum);
                                    cell.setCellValue(value);
                                    //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                                } else{
                                    cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum);
                                    cell.setCellValue("");
                                    //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                                }
                                colNum++;
                            }
                            if (!applicants.getJSONObject(i).isNull("APPLICANT_STATUS")){
                                cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum);
                                cell.setCellValue(applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString("APPLICANT_STATUS"));
                                ////dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                            }
                            else{
                                cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum);
                                cell.setCellValue("");
                                //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                            }

                            if (fieldsToTake.equals(IN_EXAM)){
                                if (applicants.getJSONObject(i).has("EXAM_STATUS_NAME")){
                                    cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum+1);
                                    cell.setCellValue(applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString("EXAM_STATUS_NAME"));
                                    //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                                    //sheet.addCell(new Label(colNum+1, rowNum, applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString("EXAM_STATUS_NAME"), cellFormat));
                                } else{
                                    cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum+1);
                                    cell.setCellValue("");
                                    //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                                    //sheet.addCell(new Label(colNum+1, rowNum, "", cellForm));
                                }
                                if (applicants.getJSONObject(i).has("NOTE")){
                                    colNum++;
                                    cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum+2);
                                    cell.setCellValue(applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString("NOTE"));
                                    //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                                    //sheet.addCell(new Label(colNum+2, rowNum, applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString("NOTE"), cellFormat));
                                }else{
                                    cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum+2);
                                    cell.setCellValue("");
                                    //dataCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("cell_normal"));
                                    //sheet.addCell(new Label(colNum+2, rowNum, "", cellForm));
                                }
                            }
                            rowNum++;
                            k++;
                        }
                        System.out.println("Time for filling ==============>" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

Comment: Which version of POI are you using? Is it a GC issue (turn on GC logging to find out)? Which POI implementation is used? HSSF, XSSF or SXSSF?

Comment: @Axel Version 3.9. XSSF.

Comment: Hmm... You could try if it happens with a newer version (3.15). But some interfaces have changed and you might have to adjust your code. Or you try SXSSF first. But are you sure the problem is with POI and not with the rest of the code? `applicants.getJSONObject(i).getString(String.valueOf(rField.getFieldId()))` could be slow too?

Comment: @Axel This method works fine with JXL. But my supervisor says that POI is faster :)). New Apache POI don't works(I have tryed before) with  webSphere Portal 7.0

Comment: @Makko any idea why you are having trouble with POI 3.15? which JVM are you using? Sun, IBM, or some other? Which version?

Comment: Apache POI ought to work on any standards-compliant JVM from 1.6 onwards. Given how much you're probably paying for websphere, vs POI for free, make use of your paid support contract, and ask IBM to help fix your/their broken setup!